# position of Pop up message box is changing at every page

Tags: visualforce

Position of Pop up message box is changing at every page.It should be come in same fashion.
It's working fine only for Home page.
...................

```
<apex:component controller="CommunityNavFooterController" allowDML="true">
      <!--script-->
      <style type="text/css">
          .popup
        {
            background-color: white;

            z-index: 9999;
            left: 50%;
            padding:40px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height:240px;
            border-radius:15px;
            border-width:2px;
            margin-left: -300px;
            top:650px;
        }

        .popupBg
        {
            background-color:black;
            opacity: 0.20;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 650px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 9998;
        }
    </style>

......

<div class="ftr-box-left one-half palm--one-whole lap--one-whole">
                <div class="ftr-links">
               <!-- <a href="/apex/CommunityFeedbackForm" style="color: #FFFFFF" target="popup" onclick='window.open("/apex/CommunityFeedbackForm", "MsgWindow","width=370, height=270")'>
                Submit Feedback
                </a>-->

                <apex:form id="feed">
                <center>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="popup">
                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBg" layout="block" rendered="{!Hide}"/>

                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popup" layout="block" rendered="{!Hide}">
                          <apex:actionRegion >
                              <apex:outputLabel style="margin-left:-74%">Submit Feedback</apex:outputLabel><br/>
                              <apex:actionFunction name="testfeedback" reRender="enablebtn"/>
                              <apex:inputTextarea value="{!Feedback}" onkeyup="testfeedback()" style="width:500px;Height:200px;resize:none"/>  
                          </apex:actionRegion>
                          <br/><br/>
                         <center>
```

Comment: I don't see "auto" listed as a valid CSS position value in e.g. [CSS position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: typo mistake.I am using   position: absolute

Comment: 1. `<center/>` is a deprecated tag. 2. You need to close off your `<div>`s and `<apex:form>`. 3. `left: 50%` is a really weird position for an absolutely positioned element. Especially in combination with `margin-left: -3000px`